# Geometric interpretation of the Dot Product

Tags: vectors

Image I have a point A = (4,4) and direction vector B = (1,0).
I know that DOT(A,B) = the distance from point A to the closest point along vector B.  If B is not normalized, I can get the distance by doing DOT(A,B) / Length(B).

However imagine the direction vector B is not normalized.  Lets say B = (6,0).
What does DOT(A, B) geometrically represent now.  The value of DOT((4,4), (6,0)) = 24 but I don't know what this actually represents.

Comment: One of the common geometric interpretations of the inner product is $\langle u, v\rangle = \|u\|\|v\|\cos(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $u$ and $v$.  If you were to divide by $\|(4,4)\|$ and $\|(6,0)\|$, you will get $\cos(\theta) = \frac{24}{4\sqrt{2}~\cdot ~6} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and thus that $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$.  Another physical interpretation is the total amount of work done by applying force along vector $u$ while traveling along vector $v$.

Comment: @JMoravitz is right to introduce the cosine function.  If you consider $\|u\|\cos(\theta)$ a length rotated outward $90^\circ$ from $\|v\|,$ you can interpret the dot product as the area of the rectangle formed by these two lengths.  See this [link]{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition}, and also this [proof-without-words of the Law of Cosines]{http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/CosineLawMolokach.shtml}..

Answer (score 1):

Define $J(v_1,v_2):=(-v_2,v_1)$, i.e., $Jv$ is the vector $v$ rotated by $\pi/2$.  Observe that the dot product of any two vectors $v$ and $w$ equals $\det(v,Jw)$.  In words: the dot product of $v$ and $w$ is the orientated area of the parallelogram spanned by $v$ and $Jw$.

Answer (score 0):

One way to define the dot product $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ is 
$$ \langle a, b \rangle = ||a||\ ||b||\ \cos\big(\angle(a,b)\big) \ .$$

If $b$ is normalized we get

$$ \langle a, b \rangle = ||a||\cos\big(\angle(a,b)\big) \ .$$

Now, imagine a right-angled triangle in which the vector $a$ points in the direction of the hypotenuse and $b$ points in the direction of one of the legs.

We see that $||a|| \cos\big(\angle(a,b)\big)$ gives the projection of $a$ in the direction of $b$.

If $b$ is not normalized we can still get the projection of $a$ along $b$ by dividing the dot product by the length $||b||$ of $b$

$$ \frac{\langle a, b \rangle}{||b||} = ||a||\cos\big(\angle(a,b)\big) \ .$$

So, to answer your question $$\text{What is the geometrical interpretation of $ \langle a, b \rangle$, in case $b$ is not normalized}:$$

it is the projection of $a$ along $b$ scaled up by the length $||b||$ of $b$.